# Yahoo Pipes trying to make twitter favorite bot

Tags: twitter, yahoo-pipes, favorite

, need to turn twitter.com/TWITTERUSER/status/377991264722894848 into https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=377991264722894848 I essentially want to know how to set it up to replace everything but the tweet ID number at the end with this beginning https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the **Regex** operator, with parameters:

- **In** = `item.twitter_url`
- **replace** = `.*/status/([0-9]+).*`
- **with** = `https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=$1`